# Android AVD Manager creating new instance at every time while running

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

**Problem :**

My Android AVD Manager creating new instance at every time while running.

I wish to run same instance at every time.

I have preselected : **Always prompt to pick device**

[image]

**Environment :**

Eclipse juno V4.2.2,Mac os x v10.8.2 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem arises normally when we are learning android.
Because I got same problem while learning android first time.
My suggestion is that we should use Android mobile to debug the application. If you will run with PC it will take too much time and sometime it will harmful for System.